# XPath to select all nodes that have text in them that is different to the text in their child nodes

Tags: php, html, xpath, webdriver

What is the most performant way to select all nodes where the text within that node is different to its child nodes.

So let’s say there is a h1 tag with a span within it. I don’t want to capture the H1 tag at all if it as like:

`<h1><span>hello</span></h1>`

I would only want to catch the span.

If it was

`<h1><span>Hello</span> World</h1>`

I need to capture them separately. So the H1 text would only be World and the span text would be Hello.

So far I have tried

`//*[normalize-space()]` but that’s gets all the elements which isn’t the desired outcome.

Is it possible maybe to to make every element an orphan so the html just becomes a 0-root document where every node is in its own node and has no parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear: what do you want to do with

```
<p><b>Hello</b><i>World</i></p>
```

and with

```
<p><b>Hello</b> <i>World</i></p>
```

?

But I think you're essentially looking for elements that have text node children (or perhaps, non-whitespace text node children) which would be

```
//*[text()]
```

or

```
//*[text()[normalize-space()]
```

respectively

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this xpath expression

```
//self::node()/text()
```

should output `Hello` and `World` separately. Try it on your actual code and see if it works.